# nvm.e SSD (960 Evo from samsung) is not recognised by BIOS or W10 (ACER Aspire VN7-591))

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bios, acer-aspire

I just received my Samsung 960 Evo NVM.e SSD (500Gb) model name MZ-V6E500.

The package looked fine (ordered from Amazon), seemingly never opened. So I opened up my computer and installed the SSD on the port left empty for it.

However, when I started my computer back up again, it wasnt detected in the file explorer. Of course, no partition. So I went to the partition Manager and only the current HDD was detected.

In the bios, same thing, no SSD detected

[image: https://imgur.com/a/FnESf]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/FnESf]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/FnESf]

Is my computer even compatible? Is the SSD broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I ended up returning it to Amazon and buying a Sata 3 inch SSD